# How to insert a cover page followed by a page break into an existing document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

The task I have is to insert the content of a cover page word document into a set of existing word documents. The existing documents all sit within a ToBeProcessed folder with the covering page stored in it's own folder. The process I have created is to store the contents of the covering page in a string then iterate through the list of existing files opening each one, selecting the start of the document using a range, inserting the text then adding a page break.

So far, everything works as expected except the fact that the page break is being inserted ahead of the covering page content. Can someone please advise how to achieve this? I've included the full content of my program in case anyone has experience of achieving the same result in a more efficient manner but from my research, the use of range seems to be best practice.

````
        const string COVERING_FOLDER = @"C:\Users\alex.grimsley1\Documents\DocmanLetters\CoveringPage";
        const string COMPLETE_FOLDER = @"C:\Users\alex.grimsley1\Documents\DocmanLetters\Complete";
        const string LOG_FOLDER = @"C:\Users\alex.grimsley1\Documents\DocmanLetters\Log";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss"));
            StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(LOG_FOLDER + @"\Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss") + @".txt");
            
            //Returns an array of strings which contains the list of filenames to be edited
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(PROCESSING_FOLDER);

            //Creates a new Application wrapper
            Application ap = new Application();

            //Open the Covering Page document
            var cp = ap.Documents.Open(COVERING_FOLDER + "\\CoveringPage.docx");

            //Copy the Covering Page contents to a variable for later use
            var cpContent = cp.Content.Text;

            //Close the Covering Page document
            cp.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

            //Loop through the file list
            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                if(file.Substring(0, PROCESSING_FOLDER.Length + 1) == PROCESSING_FOLDER + "~")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Skipping temporary file: " + file);
                } else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
                        
                        //Open each file using the Application wrapper
                        var d = ap.Documents.Open(file);
                        ap.Visible = true;
                        var dName = d.Name;

                        //Select a range at the very start of the Document
                        var rng = d.Range(0, 0);
                        d.Unprotect();
                        d.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection);

                        //Add covering page text to the Document
                        rng.Text = cpContent;
                        rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                        rng.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);

                        //Write the Document name to the Console
                        Console.WriteLine(d.Name);

                        //Save the document in place
                        d.Save();

                        //Close the document
                        d.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

                        //Move the file to the Complete folder
                        File.Move(file, COMPLETE_FOLDER + "\\" + dName);

                        //Log the completion of the letter
                        logfile.WriteLine("Complete " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + d.Name);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There was an error: " + e.Message);

                        //Log the completion of the letter
                        logfile.WriteLine("Error " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + e.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Close Word application
                        ap.Quit();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
                        ap = null;
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    }
                }
                           
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine("Processing complete...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }```
````

Comment: You know how I would do this? Open the cover page document, insert a page break after its range, then insert the to-be-processed document after that, then save the cp document with new name into the to-be-processed folder. Close. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Have you tried to `rng.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);` **first** then again select the start of your document and insert the cover page then. Basically reverse the insert order.